# Attributes and classes

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm searching to how can I know inside an attribute definition if the class I apply the attribute to, has another attribute
Example:

```
[My1Attribute]  
public class MyClass  
{   
    [My2Attribute]  
    int aux{get;set;}  

}        

internal sealed class My1Attribute : Attribute
{ 
     public My1Attribute
     {
           // How can  I Know if 'MyClass' has My2Attribute applied ???
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute itself will not know about the class to which it's attached. You will need to use some other service/helper function/whatever to pair them up.

However, you might find the following useful:

```
public static bool HasAttribute<T, TAttribute>() where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    return typeof (T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof (TAttribute), true).Any();
}
```

**Edit:** For finding attributes on member fields

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns all the (accessible) fields or properties that for a given type that
/// have the "T" attribute declared on them.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Type object to search</param>
/// <returns>List of matching members</returns>
public static List<MemberInfo> FindMembers<T>(Type type) where T : Attribute
{
    return FindMembers<T>(type, MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Property);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns all the (accessible) fields or properties that for a given type that
/// have the "T" attribute declared on them.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Type object to search</param>
/// <returns>List of matching members</returns>
public static List<MemberInfo> FindMembers<T>(Type type, MemberTypes memberTypesFlags) where T : Attribute
{
    const BindingFlags FieldBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;

    List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();
    members.AddRange(type.FindMembers(
                            memberTypesFlags,
                            FieldBindingFlags,
                            HasAttribute<T>, // Use delegate from below...
                            null)); // This arg is ignored by the delegate anyway...

    return members;
}

public static bool HasAttribute<T>(MemberInfo mi) where T : Attribute
{
    return GetAttribute<T>(mi) != null;
}

public static bool HasAttribute<T>(MemberInfo mi, object o) where T : Attribute
{
    return GetAttribute<T>(mi) != null;
}
```

Comment: But I can not use this inside the attribute

Comment: Well, you could put it as a static function, but if I were you I would use it as an extension method or in a static helper class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  but how I can know the class the attribute is binding inside the attribute itself to apply this!!?!!?! For example, I have an "OrderableAttribute" and a "DefaultOrderAttribute". If I define a class with "OrderableAttribute" I Need to check that DefaultOrderAttribute is also set

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you would need to define your rules about how you determine what members you are going to check. In your example, you're using the attributed decorated on a property, so given that you have an instance of `Type` for `MyClass` (e.g. `typeof(MyClass)`), you can grab the properties:

```
var property = type.GetProperty("aux", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (property.IsDefined(typeof(My1Attribute))) 
{
    // Property has the attribute.
}
```

(This is assuming you actually want to grab that non-public instance property, if not adjust your `BindingFlags`).

If you actually want to use the attribute:

```
var attib = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(My1Attribute), false)[0];
// Do something with the attribute instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx)?, plus here's a related question that you might find helpful: [How to check if C# class has security attribute used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439900/how-to-check-if-c-class-has-security-attribute-used)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean in general find out if any class with MyAttribute1 has My2Attribute (rather than specifically MyClass). The only way I can think of doing it is getting a list of all classes from reflection and iterating through them checking which ones have Attribute1 and then check if they have Attribute2.

I don't think you can do anything clever like automatically retrieve a list of classes with current attribute.

Comment: I want to do something similiar to that you say. Imagine I have an "Orderable" attribute and I need an "DefaultOrderAttribute". If I define a class like "Orderable" I Need to check that DEfaultOrder is also set